# Symfony - accessing twig templates both from javascript (frontend) and controllers (backend)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, templates, twig

The first way I use templates is standart symfony way - calling from controller:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:MyController:MyTemplate.html.twig');
```

The template is stored in `Resources/views/MyController/MyTemplate.html.twig`

The second way I use templates is frontend. I am using `twig.js` and templates are stored in `Resources/public/twig` folder (they are accessible from `/bundles/mybundle/twig` from js)

The problem. For example I want to use the same `macro` on the front and on the back. I can not access `views` from `public` templates and I also can not access `public` from templates, that are stored in the `views`.

Currently using Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V :/

Comment: there's no concept of path access on client-side templates, you must feed them data manually.

Comment: I understand, but maybe exists more or less elegant solution for this. The way I can do it now is not much cleaner than copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very simple solution for me:

`config.yml`

```
twig:
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Ida/BabolaBundle/Resources/public/twig": public
```

Now I can have an access from `views` to `public` using `@public/myTemplate.html.twig` in any `views` template

And here is also **PHPStorm** hint for this feauture:

Add new line in `Settings -> Other Setting -> Symfony2 Plugin -> Twig / Template`

`public src/YourVendor/YourBundle/Resources/public/twig ADD_PATH Custom true`